# Jasper Rest API, run a report

Tags: node.js, rest, report, jasperserver

I am currently trying to run a report thanks to Jasper Rest API and get the output (PDF), the interessant part of the doc is [**here**](http://www.scribd.com/doc/68405255/2/REST-Web-Services#page=30)

So I tried this : `http://localhost:8080/jasperserver/rest/report/reports/samples/report_mongodb_new_basic`

Knowing that my report is in reports/samples and its Resource ID is : `report_mongodb_new_basic`

So I still tried to run it with nodejs here is my code :
(request is a nodejs module available [here](https://github.com/mikeal/request) )

Login :

```
var request = require("request");   
request.post({url: "http://localhost:8080/jasperserver/rest/login", 
qs: {j_username: "jasperadmin", j_password: "jasperadmin"}},
function(err, res, body) {
    if(err) {
        return console.error(err);
    }
```

After login, as the doc show I need to do a PUT request to run the report :

```
     request.put("http://localhost:8080/jasperserver/rest
     /report/reports/samples/report_mongodb_new_basic")
```

This isn't working of course, even when i directly go on this url with
*Firefox*, it say

```
"Report not found (uuid not found in session)"
```

The uuid should be created thanks to this PUT request

So what is the good syntax of the URL and the good syntax of a PUT request to get the **uuid** and after if possible the pdf with a get?

Comment: Are you issuing the `request.put` call in the body of the first request callback?

Comment: Well to be honest I don't know what callback is but I guess you ask if I put `request.put` in the `request.post` (like that : `request.post(.... request.put() )` The answer is yes, but that doesn't change anything, I think my problem is in the URL

Comment: I know what a callback is now and yes I call request.put in the body of the first request callback

Answer (score 1):

jonny provided a correct answer. But here is a simpler one, using the REST_v2 interface that allows you to run and get a report output in a single request:

```
        request.get("http://localhost:8080/jasperserver/rest_v2/reports/samples/report_mongodb_new_basic.pdf")
```

This is described in section 3.2.1 of [web services documentation](http://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/jasperreports-server-web-service-guide-v500).

Comment: Hi @lionel I am new to jasper and node js. I want to invoke jasper report from node server. When I tried your code I am getting 401 unauthorized error.  Any Help?

Comment: This is not a specific error from Jasper, this is an athentification problem. You should document yourself about this HTTP error and try to solve it globally.

Comment: How to specify the path to report? Is it absolute?

Answer (score 0):

Recently I have same problem.

After login and before running you PUT, you should run GET request on

`http://localhost:8080/jasperserver/rest/report/reports/samples/report_mongodb_new_basic`

answer body is resourceDescriptor

```
 <resourceDescriptor>
 ... 
 </resourceDescriptor>
```

then you should run your PUT request **with request body set to resourceDescriptor**

you can add report parameters to report unit definition. In fact, I use XMLRemoteDatasource to fetch my data
so I add a parameter to report_unit

```
  ...
    <parameter name="XML_URL" class="java.lang.String">
        <![CDATA[http://$ENV{HTTP_HOST}/some_url]]>
    </parameter>
</resourceDescriptor>
```

this helped me for `Jasper Server 4.5 Community Edition`

Comment: GET request gives Report not found (uuid not found in session). What are we missing?

Answer (score 0):

Example of a complete script for get a Report in Jasper, but in Ruby
http://www.redrails.com.br/2013/03/07/ruby-client-para-rest-api-do-jasper-report-server/