# REST Web Service API: upload/update report template

Tags: rest, jasper-reports, jasperserver

I want to store and deploy report template with my code.

With this one in mind running a report is a two step process:

- upload or update existing report template *jrxml* (it does not have links to other resources like images)
- run it with my data (this one is [done](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9538038/jasper-rest-api-run-a-report))

The official documentation doesn't contain a minimal example for updating report template

What is raw request which uploads/updates report template *xml* via *JasperReports Server REST API*?

I tried this way

here is my [raw request](http://pastebin.com/YxeGW2bA)

here is [response](http://pastebin.com/UBXXhem3)

here what I see in [/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/jasperserver/WEB-INF/logs/jasperserver.log](http://pastebin.com/HcNqDK0X)

What am I doing wrong? What does `400 error: could not find the binary content for resource: /Reports/product_structures_workshops` mean?

Comment: Are you talking about *JR Server* or about some custom application?

Comment: I am integrating JR Server with my application

Comment: @Alex K, where I can get RESTServlet.java source code? (`com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.rest.RESTServlet`). I don't want to download entire source tree

Comment: Check [this link](http://jasperforge.org/svn/repos/jasperserver/trunk/jasperserver-rest/src/main/java/com/jaspersoft/jasperserver/rest/). Login\password: anonsvn\anonsvn

Comment: Thanks, you made my day (I found REST tests)

Comment: @Alex K, could you please update your link to jasper source code? it is now broken

Comment: Try [this one](http://code.jaspersoft.com/svn/repos/jasperserver/trunk/jasperserver-rest/src/main/java/com/jaspersoft/jasperserver/rest/)

Comment: @Jonny, could you please provide a complete solution for your problem? I.e., how to upload / update report template(s) programmatically? Is there any way to do it within the REST?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We ended up with writing proprietary local JAVA application with jasper libraries, which does same thing

It looks like this is doable in older jasper versions (> 5.2):

they simplified significally REST API (look for API v2)

https://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/getting-started-rest-web-service-api

> With the completion of the v2 REST API, Jaspersoft announces the
>   deprecation of the original REST API and the end-of-life of the SOAP
>   services

Comment: Thanks, could you also share the request example mentioned in the very first post? The documentation is still poor.

Comment: @Bosik, sorry, I lost it, but v1 API REST tests from http://code.jaspersoft.com/svn/repos/jasperserver/trunk/jasperserver-rest/src/main/java/com/jaspersoft/jasperserver/rest (anonsvn/anonsvn) repository are still available

Answer (score 2):

This works for Jasper 5.5+ (**but does not for 5.1-**, returns just `404 Not Found` "Specified page not found" instead).

#### Uploading

```
POST http://your-host:port/jasperserver/rest_v2/resources/path/to/resource/

Content-Type: application.repository.reportUnit+json

{
    "label": "Sample",
    "jrxml": {
        "jrxmlFile": {
            "label": "MyJRXML",
            "type":"jrxml",
            // encode your file in Base64 and put here
            "content": "PD94bWwg..."
        }
    }
}
```

#### Updating

```
PUT http://your-host:port/jasperserver/rest_v2/resources/path/to/resource/myReport/

Content-Type: application.repository.reportUnit+json

{
    "label": "Sample",
    "jrxml": {
        "jrxmlFile": {
            "label": "MyJRXML",
            "type":"jrxml",
            // encode your file in Base64 and put here
            "content": "PD94bWwg..."
        }
    }
}
```

References:

- https://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/822949/example-creating-report-resource-rest-v2
- http://community.jaspersoft.com/sites/default/files/docs/jasperreports-server-web-services-guide.pdf